# Save file to server viaWCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to save a `Bitmap` as a jpeg file on my website which is hosted on Hostgator, via WCF service.

Code that needs to save file looks like this

```
Bitmap bmPhoto = ...
var path = "~/httpdocs/Images/" + filename + ".jpg";
bmPhoto.Save(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

On my PC I'm using `Server.MapPath` and it works perfectly well. But I can't use `Server.MapPath` in WFC service. Instead I use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` in `System.Web.Hosting` and it doesn't work. What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: How/why doesn't it work? Do you have an exception you could share with us?

Comment: Make sure the account the service is running under at has write permissions on the directory you want to save the bitmap in.

Comment: I just find the solution. In Hostgator, website is not hosted in root folder, but in httpdocs folder, but MapPath(~/) method doesn't return root folder but httpdocs. I deleted "/httpdocs" from MapPath dapameters and now it works